# How many points are Jacks and Queens worth?

Tags: scoring

When playing the game of Cambio I have played it where Jacks and Queens are both 10 points at the end of the game.

Is this correct or are Jacks worth 11 and Queens worth 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either 10 each or 11 and 12, depending on which rules set you use.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_(game)) says it's played with cards numbered 1 through 13, sometimes with a dedicated deck and sometimes with a standard deck, indicating that the J and Q are worth 11 and 12 respectively:

> The game uses a dedicated deck of cards with each suit numbered from 1 to 13, ... Cabo can also be played with a standard playing card deck, and goes under names including Cambio,...

The reference it gives there for "standard deck Cabo" is [this one](https://treyhunner.com/2015/06/cabo-card-game/), which says

> Jack is worth 11
> Queen is worth 12
> King of diamonds (the one-eyed king) is worth 0 points
> The other three kings are worth 13 points

[This set of rules](https://manito-wish.org/assets/Cambio-Rules.pdf) also gives the 11 and 12 values:

> Points correspond almost directly with the face value of the card (Ace = 1, 2 = 2…. J = 11, Q = 12) with
> the exception of the Kings. A black King is 13 points (bummer), and a red King is NEGATIVE 2 (this is the
> best card, we like these).

While [this one](https://cambiocardgame.com/rules/) says 10:

> Face cards: 10 points
> Ace: 1
> Red King: -1
> Joker: 0

As does [this set](https://nebelmeerwanderer.wordpress.com/2017/08/16/cambio/):

> Red King: Gives you -1 points, meaning, the lowest possible score is -2 if you have both red kings and no other cards.
> All card’s worths correspond with their value: J, Q, black Kings and 10s are worth 10 points, 5 is worth five points and so on, Aces are worth 1 point.

While the [Android App rules](https://www.cambio-card-game.net/rules) are ambiguous (and I haven't installed it to see which way the app actually scores it):

> Every card is worth its number except the K of hearts and the K of diamonds, which are worth -1

Answer (score 0):

According to rules for Cambio [here](https://cambiocardgame.com/rules/) face cards, with exception of Red King, are worth 10.

As you are asked about Jacks and Queens I assume you are playing with a standard 52 card deck.  There is a very similar game commercially available called Cabo (rules [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/geekdo-files.com/bgg243175?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D%22Cabo-online-rules.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJYFNCT7FKCE4O6TA%2F20201207%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201207T192153Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=120&X-Amz-Signature=65bfd582654f4f3984331949749a8e5c61b237411a516df57d350b2700ec8133) ) that has cards numbered so there are no Jacks and Queens and reading those rules it seems that the score is the face value of the card.